# How do I convert this XML to KML?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, google-maps, kml

I am a little new to this, but I need to convert the below XML to KML format so I can feed it into Google maps. Can anyone help with this?

```
<messageList>
<totalCount>1</totalCount>
−
<message>
<esn>0-7396996</esn>
<esnName>JOHN</esnName>
<messageType>TEST</messageType>
<messageDetail> ALL IS WELL AT CURRENT LOCATION.</messageDetail>
<timestamp>2010-05-24T00:39:12.000Z</timestamp>
<timeInGMTSecond>1274661552</timeInGMTSecond>
<latitude>25.19483</latitude>
<longitude>65.7162</longitude>
</message>
</messageList>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could apply an XSL template translator. Something along these lines:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
        <Document>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="messageList" />
        </Document>
    </kml>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="messageList">
    <name>My Generated KML</name>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="message" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="message">
    <Placemark>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="esnName" /></name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>
                <xsl:value-of select="latitude" />,<xsl:value-of select="longitude" />
            </coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(basic KML format from [a documentation example](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/extendeddata.html))

KML is an extensive format, and you can add much more information than the couple of elements I have here.

Answer (score 0):

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

        // Create the root element
        XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("kml");
        rootNode.SetAttribute("xmlns", @"http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1");
        xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        // Add the Document
        XmlElement documentNode = CreateElement(xmlDoc, "Document", "Test KML File");
        rootNode.AppendChild(documentNode);
        xmlDoc.Save(outputFilePath + FileName + ".kml");


    public XmlElement CreateElement(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string elementType, string name)
    {
        XmlElement documentNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement(elementType);
        XmlElement documentNameNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("name");
        XmlText nameText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(name);
        documentNode.AppendChild(documentNameNode);
        documentNameNode.AppendChild(nameText);
        return documentNode;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).